# calculating the speed of 10GBASE-T

Tags: networking, network-programming

I want to convert the speed of port into Mb/s.
Could you please let me know what would be the Mb/s of 100/1000/10GBASE-T ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, then:

Number in 100BASE-T for instance, stands for speed.

So in your case, the port supports speeds of 100Mb/s, 1000Mb/s and 10Gb/s respectively.

Comment: Hi Nikit, the specification is as follows,  Port Configuration 100/1000/10 GBASE-T . Is it not the GBASE-T same for 100/1000/10? in that case i would like to know what will be Mb/s for these speeds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what speeds are you willing to know? As the number 100/1000/10 represent the speed in Mb/s. As for the last number 10, the speed is in Gb/s. So 10 Gb/s = 10000 Mb/s. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: The specification file says like this : Port speed (100/1000/10 GBase-T) . I am trying to understand whether it is represented in Mb/s or Gb/s.Initially i thought (100 and 1000 are also GBase-T ports).

Comment: oh, ok. So it means that this port supports interfaces with 100 Mb/s, 1000Mb/s and 10Gb/s.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Nikit.

Answer (score -1):

The current wired ethernet on UTP standards are:

- !0BASE-T = 10 Mbps
- 100BASE-TX = 100 Mbps (notice the "X," 100BASE-T is obsolete)
- 1000BASE-T = 1000 Mbps or 1 Gbps
- 10GBASE-T = 10000 Mbps or 10 Gbps